# How to delete a file using PHP - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter framework, and the column 'file' contains the URL of the file. And whenever I execute this I get this: 
Message: unlink() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given.
Help me solve this...

```
$this->db->select('file');
$this->db->from('images');
$imageurl=$this->db->where('id',$id);
unlink($imageurl) or die("Couldn't delete file");
```

Comment: try to print the $imageurl variable and pass correct path to unlink

Comment: What does `echo $imageurl` yields ?

Comment: I tried echo $imageurl; nothing happens, as this is placed in gallery_model.php in models directory..

Comment: so, the problem is on `$this->db->where('id',$id);` or before it

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return?

Comment: Try var_dump($imageurl) instead of echo $imageurl

Comment: I get the same error, i think the data returned is not of string type...

Comment: I got this http://prntscr.com/f8zfrr after placing var_dump($imageurl)

Comment: You can't delete by URL, you'll need a physical path.

Comment: $imageurl is an object. From that find the element which has image url. Try to run the query in mysql or phpadmin and check the results

Comment: Yes, the 'file' column consists of path not url.@gabriel-heming

Comment: $this->db->select('file');
$this->db->from('images');
$imageurl=$this->db->where('id',$id);
This should have returned the path of the image, which is a string. So how did $imageurl was returned an object @RavinderReddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your query this should be correct:

```
$this->db->select('file');
$this->db->from('images');
$this->db->where('id',$id);
$resSQL = $this->db->get();
if ($resSQL->num_rows() > 0) {
        $resultRaw = $resSQL->result_array();
        $result = $resultRaw[0];
        $imageurl = $result['imageurl'];

        // Also for unlink any file you need to pass the relative path of that file like: /folder/sub-folder/file-name So, in this case if you are storing image url in database then use str_replace to replace some part of string.
           unlink($imageurl) or die("Couldn't delete file");
    }
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Worked thank you so much.
If you could can you tell me, why use used this 
$resultRaw = $resSQL->result_array();
$result = $resultRaw[0];
$imageurl = $result['imageurl'];

Comment: Without using $resSQL->result_array(); you can not fetch data returned from query. It returns an array. As you are using primary key $id so you will get only one record and that one record will come at zero index of array. That is why I used this: $result = $resultRaw[0].  For more info paste these line below fetch_array() line.  echo '<pre>'; print_array($resultRaw); die;